# What is the easiest way to foreach through a List<T> removing unwanted objects?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, list, collections

In my application, _collection is a List from which I need to **remove all User objects** which do not match the **criteria**.

However, the following code gets an **invalid operation** error in its second iteration since the _collection itself has been changed:

```
foreach (User user in _collection)
{
    if (!user.IsApproved())
    {
        _collection.Remove(user);
    }
}
```

I could create another List collection and copy them back and forth but then I have the issue of non-cloned reference types, etc.

**Is there a way to do the above more elegantly than copying _collection to another  another List variable?**

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
_collection.RemoveAll(user => !user.IsApproved());
```

If you're *still* on 2.0:

```
_collection.RemoveAll(delegate(User u) { return !u.IsApproved(); });
```

By the way, if you don't want to touch the original list, you can get *another* list of approved users with:

```
_collection.FindAll(user => user.IsApproved());
```

Comment: Or `_collection.FindAll(user => user.IsApproved());` to eliminate negations.

Comment: _collection.FindAll will return **another** collection. It's quite different from changing the initial collection (there might be cases when some other objects hold references to the same list and you need that one changing, rather than creating another).

Answer (score 4):

You can always start at the top index and iterate downward towards 0:

```
for (int i = _collection.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    User user = _collection[i];
    if (!user.IsApproved())
    {
        _collection.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

Mehrdad's answer looks pretty darn elegant, though.

Comment: This appears to contain a bug.  Consider the case of a collection with two elements, the first of which is not approved.  The first is removed, so collection[1] becomes outs of bounds.

Comment: Steven: In the case you describe the above code would have already checked collection[1] (which after removing collection[0] becomes collection[0]) since it is iterating from the top down. So there shouldn't be any out-of-bounds error.

Comment: It's fine.  Walk through it again and you'll see it's okay.

Comment: For those of us still on .NET 2.0, this method is the way to go.

Comment: @C-Pound Guru: `List<T>.RemoveAll` has been there since 2.0: `list.RemoveAll(delegate(User u) { return !u.IsApproved(); });`

Answer (score 0):

Whenever there is a chance that a collection will be modified in a loop, opt for a `for` loop instead. The solution given by Mehrdad is lovely and definitely worth a try!

Here's code I find helpful when dealing with modifiable collections:

```
for(int index=0;index < _collection.Count; index++)
{
    if (!_collection[index].IsApproved)
    {
        _collection.RemoveAt(index);
        index--;
    }
}
```