# Remove instances from a list by using LINQ or Lambda?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Now I come a stage to get all my data as a list in cache(objects) and my next thing I have to do is to remove some instances from the list.

Normally, I would do removing like this:

```
List<T> list;
List<T2> toBeRemovedItems;
// populate two lists
foreach(T2 item in toBeRemovedItems)
{
    list.Remove(delegate(T one) { 
        // build a condition based on item
        // return true or false
    });
}
```

To be more specific, I actually build or populate toBeRemvoedItems list of a dynamic class (not a formal defined class). For example, the T class is something like MyClass and codes for removing are:

```
class MyClass<C> {
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public int Value2 { get; set; }
    public C ObjectC { get; set; }
}
....
List<MyClass<C>> list;
// populate list
// populate toBeRemovedItems. Here is an example of hard-coded codes:
var toBeRemovedLItems = new[] {
    new { Value1="a", Value2 = 1},
    new { Value2="x", Value2 = 10},
    ...
};
// toBeRemovedItems may be the result of Select from a collection
foreach(var item in toBeRemovedLItems)
{
    list.Remove(delegate(MyClass one) {
        return one.Value1 = item.Value1 && one.Value2 < item.Value2;
    });
}
```

I tried to search for `Remove()` method in `IEnumerable` interface from MSDN, but I cannot find the method of `Remove()` there (it makes sense that `IEnumerable` is used just for enumeration). In List class, there are several overloaded `Remove(...)` methods. I am not sure if there any alternative ways to remove items from a list by using LINQ or Lambda expressions?

By the way, I thought about a way to do a query against a list to get a subset or a new `IEnumerable` list with Where conditions, similar as moving items from a list. However, I prefer to remove items from my cached list, and there some cases I just cannot reset list property in a class to a new list (private set for example).

Comment: Looks like a dupe. Well, basically you mentioned all possible methods in the post itself... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120336/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-foreach-through-a-listt-removing-unwanted-objects

Answer (score 45):

You could use the method **RemoveAll**:

```
MyClass one; //initialize MyClass
list.RemoveAll(item => one.Value1 == item.Value1 && one.Value2 < item.Value2);
```

Comment: i think it's actually a method of List<T>, not an extension method

Comment: My understanding your codes is that you remove one item at a time. Still I have to loop each just like Rchard Hein's suggestion.

Answer (score 22):

You can use LINQ's Where method to filter out values that should not be a part of the list.  The result is an `IEnumerable<T>` with the elements removed.

```
var res = list.Where(item => !(one.Value1 == item.Value1 && one.Value2 < item.Value2));
```

This will not updated the original `List<T>` instance but instead will create a new `IEnumerable<T>` with the values removed.

Comment: What's the perf. hit doing this vs. a for loop removing the items?

Answer (score 5):

If I get the question correctly, to produce a unique set from two List.

For this, you can use the following

List list1;
List list2;

List list3 = list1.Except(list2)

The list3 will contain unique items.

Comment: This is the first answer that addresses my goal, which is to both remove and receive the enumeration of objects matching the lambda.

Comment: Must be the same kind of collection for this to work, though.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Jared's suggestion of filtering out certain items, but it looks like a `join` on `Value1` would be a more efficient approach:

```
var res = from item1 in list
          join item2 in toBeRemovedList
            on item1.Value1 equals item2.Value1
          where item1.Value2 >= item2.Value2
          select item1;
```

**Update:** Apparently I fail at reading comprehension - new approach:

```
var removeDict = toBeRemovedList.ToDictionary(i => i.Value1, i => i.Value2);
list.RemoveAll(item => {
    int itemToRemoveValue2;
    if(removeDict.TryGetValue(item.Value1, out itemToRemoveValue2))
        return item.Value2 < itemToRemoveValue2;
    return false;
});
```

Of course, it would be even better if your list to remove could start as a dictionary. Ultimately, we're just trying to make our match on `Value1` more efficient.

Comment: Is the join similar as SQL Intersect? or this LINQ query like that?

Comment: Anyway, as I mentioned in my question, if the list property is not settable, I cannot use this strategy. It is good way only I have control the list.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach(var item in toBeRemovedLItems) {   
   list.RemoveAll(one => one.Value1 == item.Value1 && one.Value2 < item.Value2); 
}
```

Too late again.  Oh well.

Comment: Not sure if it is possible to pass two parameters to the RemoveAll(lambda func) to remove a toBeRemovedItems, without through foreach loop. For sure it is already very readable.

Answer (score 1):

For collections that are not lists (can't expose `RemoveAll`), you can still remove items with a one-liner.

To replace inline, just generate a list of items to remove, then run through it and execute remove code.

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>(){{"foo", "0"}, {"boo", "1"}, {"goo", "1"}};
dictionary
    .Where(where_item =>
        ((where_item.Key == "foo") && (where_item.Value == "0"))
        || ((where_item.Key == "boo") && (where_item.Value == "1"))
    )
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(remove_item => {
        dictionary.Remove(remove_item.Key);
    });
```

To replace in copy, just generate a filtered enumerable and return a new copy.

```
var dictionary0 = new Dictionary<string, string>(){{"foo", "0"}, {"boo", "1"}, {"goo", "1"}};
var dictionary1 = dictionary0
    .Where(where_item =>
        ((where_item.Key == "foo") && (where_item.Value == "0"))
        || ((where_item.Key == "boo") && (where_item.Value == "1"))
    )
    .ToDictionary(each_item => each_item.Key, each_item => each_item.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're trying to do something like this?

```
List<T> firstList;
List<T2> toBeRemovedItems;
List<T> finalList;

foreach(T item in firstList)
{
    toBeRemovedItems = CheckIfWeRemoveThisOne(item.Number, item.Id);
    if (toBeRemovedItems == null && toBeRemovedItems.Count() == 0)
        finalList.Add(item);
}
```

This is how I managed to solve an issue with getting rid of duplicates between a `List<ViewModel>` and a `List<Model>`.  I used the `CheckIfWeRemoveThisOne` function to check if the `item.Number` belonged to some other item, using the ID as the defining characteristic.  If it found another item (a duplicate), rather than try and remove it from the original list (which I was getting back a `List<Model>` and was given a `List<ViewModel>` into my function in the first place, so I had my doubts as to how I could do it, anyway), I just built a new list -- adding the result into it if it was found to be ok.