# C# Using .Remove In List<Category>

Tags: c#, list, properties

Trying to use .remove to remove stuff from my List.. but it's not working, giving me the error "Argument type 'string' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.Predicate'

```
  public void ManiPulateCategory(string categoryToManipulate)
   {
       createCategories = repository.Load(path);


       foreach (Category item in createCategories)
       {
          createCategories.Remove(item.CategoryName)
           }
       }
```

Comment: You need to pass in a `Remove` method object of type `Category` as an argument, while you are passing `string`

Comment: There are a few potential problems here. The `Remove` method takes `T` as an argument, in this case `Category`. But you cannot modify a list that is being iterated via its enumerator, you'll get another error. The `Remove` method then uses the equality implementation of the type, or the default equality implementation if one isn't found.

Comment: foreach (Category item in createCategories)
           {
              createCategories.Remove(item);
               }   // gives me no error but its not doing what I want it to do.

Comment: Please, read this help article
[What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Also tags in a question title are redundant.

Comment: Note that SO is not a forum. You don't need to include the right answer in a question. If your want to post your own solution then just post it as an answer instead.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you are trying to remove from your list of categories ALL items that have a `CategoryName` which matches `categoryToManipulate`.

If that's what you want, you can do it using [`List.RemoveAll()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like so:

```
createCategories.RemoveAll
(
     catagory => catagory.CategoryName == categoryToManipulate
);
```

This is using a method on `List`, NOT something from `IEnumerable`. If you only have an `IEnumerable` available, you would have to use a different solution - but you said you have a `List`, so this should work.

This works by you passing what's known as a *predicate* to `RemoveAll()`. A predicate is simply a method takes a single parameter of a certain type and that returns true or false. It will be called once for each element of the list, being passed that element as a parameter. If it returns true, that element will be removed.

In this case, I didn't create a separate method for the predicate; instead I wrote an inline [`lambda expression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb397687.aspx) to implement it.

Comment: @DangerCoder if you want to appreciate someone, you may want to use standard SO mechanisms for that - like accepting an answer and upvoting.

Answer (score 1):

```
createCategories.RemoveAll(x=>x.CategoryName == categoryToManipulate)
```

Something like that? (Fixed to reflect comments but initially proposed by Matthew Watson above)

Also have a look at this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185323/remove-instances-from-a-list-by-using-linq-or-lambda)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this code will throw an exception in the loop due to the collection being modified. And even if it didn't throw an exception, it would just remove all items from the collection.

Comment: Fair enough, my answer was based on the error ""Argument type 'string' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.Predicate'". Was illustrating the predicate. Perhaps I should have been a little more verbose :)

Comment: Should I remove this answer as fixing it would be a duplicate of what Matthew Watson posted?

Comment: Well it's up to you, but there's little point in having duplicate answers (other than retaining any votes you may have got, of course! :)

Comment: @RabidDog5150 Downvoted exactly for reasons Matthew Watson gave you. Since the code has been corrected, I revoked the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the right item in a list you have to override Equals and GetHashCode from Object.

```
class Category  {
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is Category)) return false;
        return this.CategoryName == ((Category)obj).CategoryName;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        this.CategoryName.GetHashCodeU();
    }
}
```

Now you may call `createCategories.remove(item)` within your loop.

Comment: Regarding "Now you may call `createCategories.remove(item)` within your loop": you cannot simultaneously enumerate a list and remove items from it, because you'll get `InvalidOperationException`.